# Binary Search Optimization

Tags: c#, reinventing-the-wheel, binary-search

Can anyone give me recommendations on how to improve my code?

```
using System;
namespace mybinsearch2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int key = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] arr = new int[n];  int min = 0;int max = n - 1;
            int mid = min + (max - min) / 2;int temp;
            for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = i *5;
            }
            while (true)
            {
                temp = arr[mid];
                if (arr[mid] == key)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Position is: " + mid); break;
                }
                else if (arr[mid] < key) min = mid;
                else max = mid;
                mid = min + (max - min) / 2;
                if(arr[mid]==temp)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Not Found"); break;
                }
            }

       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Step 1: use much better (longer) names.

Comment: Step 2: group lines together more logically. The first `mid = ...` statement isn't used in the fill loop, so it should come after it.

Comment: If you have repeating values I think the second if(arr[mid]==temp) can fail.

Comment: I would recommend putting each statement on a new line, e.g. `Console.WriteLine("Not Found"); break;` should be two lines. It made the break statements a lot easier to miss.

Comment: What problem does your code solve? We're missing context here.

Comment: The basic approach for binary search is to make sure your search range min .. max always decreases in the loop. And then something like `while(min < max)` could replace the rather useless `while(true)`

Comment: I gave a few hints [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/153422/13165)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have repeating values I think the second `if(arr[mid]==temp)` can fail.

Separate the create the test from the program (method).  Return a value from method and print it in the test.

The first `if (arr[mid] == key)` that is the least likely condition so put it last and  it can just be an else as you should test for < and > so = is all that is left.

You repeatedly reference `arr[mid]` when you already have it `temp = arr[mid];`

You have `max = n - 1;` but you don't use it in the create test loop

Put assignments on separate lines
This still has problems - this is just cleaning up existing code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int key = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    int min = 0;
    int max = n - 1;
    int mid = min + (max - min) / 2;
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = i * 5;  
    }
    while (true)
    {
        temp = arr[mid];
        if (temp < key)
        {
            min = mid;  // this seems backwards but that is what you have
        }
        else if (temp > key)
        {
            max = mid;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Position is: " + mid);
            break;
        }
        mid = min + (max - min) / 2;
        if (arr[mid] == temp)  // this still has problems
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not Found");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How could I stop the loop if we have repeating values? Also, why do you say that I don't use "max = n - 1;" ? I use it when defining mid in the loop.

Comment: @nikolay Fundamentally change the algorithm.  Wiki has a good implementation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: Downvote may I ask what the problem is?

Comment: There is no problem, I just wanted to see how I can optimize the code.

Comment: @nikolay But there are problems

Comment: I want to fix the code, without fundamentally changing it, so that it works without problems arising from repeating values.

Comment: @nikolay Your code has some fundamental problems.  Upon review I don't think it is even working code.   Again just follow the simple wiki implementation.